# StorCli Wrong Physical Disk Size

Tags: raid, hardware-raid, raid5, arch-linux

I am using a 2008 MegaRAID SAS 8888ELP. I was unable to boot into webbios, although I was able to install storcli onto my arch linux setup. The raid works well although I am new to using raid and storcli.

Currently, when I run `storcli /c0 show` this is the result:

```
Controller = 0
Status = Success
Description = None

Product Name = MegaRAID SAS 8888ELP
Serial Number = P037780510
SAS Address =  500605b001d4afa0
PCI Address = 00:01:00:00
System Time = 10/17/2016 21:02:12
Mfg. Date = 02/06/10
Controller Time = 10/17/2016 21:02:11
FW Package Build = 9.0.1-0038
FW Version = 1.20.42-0525
BIOS Version = 2.01.00
Driver Name = megaraid_sas
Driver Version = 06.811.02.00-rc1
Vendor Id = 0x1000
Device Id = 0x60
SubVendor Id = 0x1000
SubDevice Id = 0x1006
Host Interface = PCI-E
Device Interface = SAS-3G
Bus Number = 1
Device Number = 0
Function Number = 0
Total foreign drive groups = 0
Physical Drives = 3

PD LIST :
=======

-------------------------------------------------------------------------
EID:Slt DID State DG     Size Intf Med SED PI SeSz Model              Sp 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
252:0    44 UGood -  1.999 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B TOSHIBA DT01ACA300 U  
252:4    46 UGood -  1.999 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B ST4000DM000-1F2168 U  
252:5    45 UGood -  1.999 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B ST3000DM001-9YN166 U  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

EID-Enclosure Device ID|Slt-Slot No.|DID-Device ID|DG-DriveGroup
DHS-Dedicated Hot Spare|UGood-Unconfigured Good|GHS-Global Hotspare
UBad-Unconfigured Bad|Onln-Online|Offln-Offline|Intf-Interface
Med-Media Type|SED-Self Encryptive Drive|PI-Protection Info
SeSz-Sector Size|Sp-Spun|U-Up|D-Down|T-Transition|F-Foreign
UGUnsp-Unsupported|UGShld-UnConfigured shielded|HSPShld-Hotspare shielded
CFShld-Configured shielded|Cpybck-CopyBack|CBShld-Copyback Shielded
```

The size of the disks say `1.999 TB`. If you look to the right a bit it describes the actual size of the disks. `ST4000DM000` is a `4 TB` drive, `ST3000DM001` is a `3TB` drive, and the toshiba is a `3TB`.

Why does it show up as `2TB`?
How can I tell the raid that they are larger drives?

Any storcli commands I can use to do this?

Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to update the firmware on your controller.
I had the same problem (as near as i can tell) on my RS2BL08 controller (intel) and after updating firmware of controllers i could expand disks to larger size.